# Estimated Time of Arrival using apple

Tags: map-directions

Does apple give any api to calculate eta(Estimated Time of Arrival) between two locations like google directions api does?if yes then kindly give some reference of it.

Comment: In an iOS App? Mac App? Safari?

Comment: Yes In iOS app only and the locations are get  from cllocation manager.

Comment: did you ever find the answer to this?